# ASP.Net MVC + Scaffolding + Authorization

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, authorization

I like the built-in scaffolding functionality that MVC has nowdays. And I've seen where this can be enhanced in a lot of ways. Curious if there is anything out there that can assist with wiring up some authorization logic within the scaffolded code? By default the generated code is open to the public. Even if it just generated stubs that forced one to go add the various portions needed for authorization, this would be a good leg up on the task and enforce coverage.

Comment: All that Scaffolding is useful for is creating some quick mock-ups. But once you start writing real world applications that require customization, scaffolding is as useful as a submarine in the Sahara desert. You get rid of it, you define view models and start writing real applications that have some real use :-)

Comment: I agree to an extent, but on the other hand- the larger the app, the more hand mapping you wind up churning out between models and views and etc etc. I see tools like scaffolding, if they were done correctly, as a way to help build even large complex apps much more quickly. Since many apps are just a glorified stack of forms on top of models on top of databases anyway...

Comment: also: appreciate your opinion, but doesn't really address the question.